# Datadog dogstream custom parser error

Tags: python, datadog

I wanted to add my custom log parser through dogstream, but there was an exception while restarting datadog agent:

```
2015-04-29 19:19:06 MSK | INFO | dd.collector | checks.collector(datadog.py:117) | Instantiating function-based dogstream
2015-04-29 19:19:06 MSK | INFO | dd.collector | checks.collector(datadog.py:124) | dogstream: parsing /var/www/api.clearspending.ru_v3/api/var/log/tornadoCS9031.log with <function parse_api_response_time at 0x7f9d0981a398> (requested dogstream/clearspending_parser:parse_api_response_time)
2015-04-29 19:19:06 MSK | INFO | dd.collector | checks.collector(datadog.py:67) | Dogstream parsers: [<checks.datadog.Dogstream object at 0x7f9d09820410>]
2015-04-29 19:19:07 MSK | INFO | dd.collector | checks.collector(collector.py:486) | Hostnames: {'socket-hostname': 'clearspending.ru', 'hostname': 'clearspending.ru', 'socket-fqdn': 'clearspending.ru'}, tags: {}
2015-04-29 19:19:07 MSK | ERROR | dd.collector | checks.collector(unix.py:370) | Cannot extract IO statistics
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/agent/checks/system/unix.py", line 284, in check
    io.update(self._parse_linux2(stdout))
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/agent/checks/system/unix.py", line 185, in _parse_linux2
    recentStats = output.split('Device:')[2].split('\n')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The parser code:

```
def parse_api_response_time(logger, line):
    """
    Just parser API log :)
    parse_api_response_time(None, "16-02-2015 15:46:36     INFO     200 GET /apishechka/v3/contracts/select/?customerregion=29&get_report=True&sort=-price (127.0.0.1) 28102.86ms")
    ('api_time', 1424090796.0, 28102.86, {})
    """
    metric_name = "api_time"
    date, status, time_response = re.match(API_LOG_REGEX, line).groups()
    date = mktime(datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
    attr_dict = {}
    # Convert the time_response value into a float
    metric_value = float(time_response[:-2])
    # Return the output as a tuple
    return (metric_name, date, metric_value, attr_dict)
```

Does anybody know why such thing happend? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The exception you are seeing is related to the IO system metrics collection and has nothing to do with your custom dogstream parser.

If you look at the stack trace it says that it wasn't able to apply the `_parse_linux2` function. To troubleshoot that further you should take a look at the output of

```
/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/bin/iostat -d 1 2 -x -k
```

which is the command launched by the agent. Feel free to open a bug on the agent GitHub repository.

References:

- https://github.com/DataDog/dd-agent/blob/5.3.2/checks/system/unix.py#L184-L185
- https://github.com/DataDog/dd-agent/blob/5.3.2/checks/system/unix.py#L264-L284